# Laravel Socialite Twitter Provider - Could not authenticate

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm using Laravel Socialite in a project and added the Twitter Provider in order to be able to allow my users to integrate with their Twitter account. I followed the steps here https://socialiteproviders.com/Twitter/ and I'm getting the following error:

```
Received HTTP status code [401] with message "{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}" when getting temporary credentials.
```

If I leave the TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI in my env file blank, the error goes away and the Oauth flow works exactly as it's supposed to. Is anyone else having this issue? If the TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI isn't needed why have it in the docs?

Comment: I found a similar package that actually removes the oauth_callback if it's provided which is odd considering the Twitter Documentation claims it's a required parameter. https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/d2fdb233ddd35be449ab62b13ff412aca61511e2/src/TwitterOAuth.php#L537 So I removed the oauth_callback parameter from the request header and sure enough, everything still worked as expected. I'm confused ‍♂️